# Framework for validating a HTTP Server/Client against HTTP 1.1 spec

Tags: http, netty

I have a Java runtime with HTTP listener and the sender side based on Netty. 
And I need to verify my java runtime for spec compliancy. Do we have any validation framework available for HTTP 1.1 specification?

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate?

- Do you mean HTTP 1.1 conformance?
- Or do you mean "your" API (REST I suppose or equivalent) conformance? For the second I could suggest various tools that define a REST interface and then alow to build a "validation" tool (as with Swagger or Raml).

Comment: I meant HTTP 1.1 conformance. Do we have a framework to validate it?